# Very slow response for Google Cloud Machine Learning training job

Tags: python, tensorflow, google-cloud-platform, gcloud, google-cloud-sdk

UPDATED: I'm submitting a Machine Learning training job using the Google Cloud Platform command line, following the [guidelines here](https://cloud.google.com/ml-engine/docs/how-tos/training-jobs#before_you_begin). I've defined local paths to my Python package, the job name, the main module for GC to run, and the other variables required by gcloud. When I run the following command to upload my package and submit a job:

`gcloud ml-engine jobs submit training $JOB_NAME \
--package-path $TRAINER_PACKAGE_PATH \
--module-name $MAIN_TRAINER_MODULE \
--job-dir $JOB_DIR \
--region $REGION \
--config config.yaml \
--staging-bucket $PACKAGE_STAGING_LOCATION \
-- \
--verbosity DEBUG`

, the job submit takes about 45 minutes before any logs or messages appear. The package I am uploading during the job submit is only code, not large amounts of data or anything. Is this normal? Is there a way to speed the process up?

Thanks,

Comment: Is the whitespace in `-- job-dir` intentional? And do you really mean `-- \ ` or is there an argument missing?

Comment: I deleted the whitespace in `--job-dir`, and the blank line is necessary to add the `--verbosity` argument.

Comment: Can you file a bug at the [Cloud SDK issue tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=187143&template=800102)?